# Asp.Net Core 6 Web Api CORS error when changing launchSettings.json profile and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to staging

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I have a .net core 6 web api and an angular application. When I run my api locally with any profile from launchSettings.json other than CourseScheduler.Api.Development, I receive a CORS error.

I have attempted AllowAnyOrigin() and WithOrigin("http://localhost:4200") instead without any success.

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and cannot understand why this is happening. The only differences between the profiles in the launchSettings.json file is the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable.

Here is my launchSettings.json file and my Program.cs file. Any help would GREATLY be appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services
    .AddSingleton<IGraphClient, GraphClient>()
    .AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>()
    .AddTransient<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        },
options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("OrganizationAdmin", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("extension_Role", "organization-admin");
    });

});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        b =>
        {
            b.WithOrigins(builder.Configuration["SPAUrl"]).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

//Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:35606",
      "sslPort": 44353
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "CourseScheduler.Api.Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7160;http://localhost:5160",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "CourseScheduler.Api.Staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7160;http://localhost:5160",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    },
    "CourseScheduler.Api.Production": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7160;http://localhost:5160",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you get value from `appsettings.json` in `WithOrigins(xxx)` and only in `Development` environment can work well, SO maybe some thing wrong when you read value from `appsettings.json` in different environment. Do you override `appsettings.json`? Or you configure data in `appsettings.Development.Json`

Comment: I have tried AllowAnyOrigin() and "http://localhost:4200" instead without success. I have also restarted visual studio many times, cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Comment: It's very strange, In your code, no matter what the environment, Their urls are the same.

Comment: Yes, very strange and frustrating. Thanks for looking into my issue